# How to sync two CSS animation timings

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a CSS animation to sync up so that a progress bar fills and a background changes at the same time.

For instance, in my example, it should take 5000ms for the progress bar and then every 5000ms the background image should change.

I thought I had this setup correctly setting my animation duration for the background to 20000ms and each step changing in intervals of 25% but this just isn't syncing correctly.

Am I missing something here or is it not really feasible to get something like this to sync accurately?

```css
.progress-bar {
width: 100%;
height: 30px; 
background-color: black;
}

.progress-bar > div {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30px;
    animation: progress-bar 5000ms linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    animation: bg 20000ms linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes progress-bar {
    0% {
        width: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes bg {
   0% {background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water");}
   25% {background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?mountain");}
   50% {background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?tree");}
   75% {background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?river");}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="progress-bar"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good, you need to avoid transition by adding more steps

```css
.progress-bar {
width: 100%;
height: 30px; 
background-color: black;
}

.progress-bar > div {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30px;
    animation: progress-bar 5000ms linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    animation: bg 20000ms linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes progress-bar {
    0% {
        width: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes bg {
   0%,24.9% {background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water");}
   25%,49.9% {background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?mountain");}
   50%,74.9% {background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?tree");}
   75%,100% {background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?river");}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="progress-bar"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you!